# Boost 1.45 dataset workaround

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, c++98

I'm making an attempt at setting boost's unit test framework up for myself, but due to having to use C++98, I also have to use boost 1.45. Due to this, I find I can't make use of datasets the way I'd like (have test cases that have an arity of 2 and a dataset of pairs (input_val,expected_val)). It's looking like I'll be able to get an approximation going using a global fixture (The fixtures would have to be global if I want to not have it reset every test case. This issue is documented in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510256/boost-test-initialization-for-each-suite-not-case)), but I dislike the idea of throwing all that into global. Does anybody know a better, possibly more elegant solution?

Comment: For C++98, I'd use [Catch](https://github.com/menzi11/Catch) for unit testing.  (Catch2 is for C++14 and later.)

Comment: Catch is beautiful and perfect for what I need. Their approach to my issue is clever and intuitive. I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: I used Catch for many years.  At work, we're using C++14, we use Boost Test and Google Test (for different parts of the system, by different teams).  I've used Catch2 (C++14 and later), but I like [doctest](https://github.com/doctest/doctest) even better and is what I'm currently using at home for my C++17 projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ provided the info I needed. If anybody else is looking for a good unit testing framework for C++98, [Catch](https://github.com/menzi11/Catch) seems great so far!